# Rerendering component and useReducer initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-reducer

EDIT: below the line is the initial problem where I asked if my whole architecture was fine. I later edited the topic (and title) to go straight to what was my issue in order to help the community. Therefore, you might find what you want by jumping directly to the answer while skipping the main post

---

I am new to react and I am encountering issues back to back. I suspect that something is wrong in my pattern and would really love to have it criticized by someone a bit stronger.

**Component A:**

It renders (among others) a Component B

*Component A* has a useState hook on an array of C_obj it renders, called `C_obj_arr`

```js
const [C_obj_arr, ASetter] = useState<C_obj[]>()
```

It provides this `C_obj_arr` and `ASetter` to *Component B* as properties to allow the data to go back up.

**Component B**
It renders each `C_obj` of the `C_obj_arr` in a list of Component C.

It has a useReducer hook that controls the states of `C_obj_arr`

```js
const [C_obj_array, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, props.C_obj_array);
```

It has a useEffect hook such that if `C_obj_arr` changes, data goes back up to Compoennt A

```js
useEffect(() => {
      ASetter(C_obj_array);
  }, [C_obj_array, ASetter]);
```

Question: Is it fine so far to use the prop like this to init the reducer?

it also uses a useCallback hook to wrap a function that will allow getting the data back from Component C

```js
  const fn_callback = useCallback(
    (c: C_obj) =>
      dispatch({
        kind: Kind.AN_ACTION,
        payload: { wells_plan: c },
      }),
    []
  );
```

**Component C**

It has another useReducer that controls the states of `C_obj`

```js
const [C_obj, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, props.C_obj);
```

To send the information back up to *Component B*, it uses the function `fn_callback`, created in B thanks to a useEffect hook with dep on `C_obj`

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fn_callback(C_obj);
  }, [C_obj, props.fn_callback]);
```

I hope it is not a total brain schmuck to read, I am very new to all of that so I understand I can be doing something totally broken by design.
Many thanks for help

EDIT: as requested, here is a block of code to synthetize

```js
const A = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [C_obj_arr, ASetter] = useState<C_obj[]>();

  return (
    <>
      <B>C_obj_arr=C_obj_arr ASetter=ASetter</B>
    </>
  );
};

const B = (C_obj_arr_init: C_obj[], ASetter: () => void): JSX.Element => {
  const [C_obj_array, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, C_obj_arr_init);

  useEffect(() => {
    ASetter(C_obj_array);
  }, [C_obj_array, ASetter]);

  const fn_callback = useCallback(
    (c_obj: C_obj) =>
      dispatch({
        kind: Kind.UPDATE_OBJ,
        payload: { wells_plan: c_obj },
      }),
    []
  );

  return C_obj_array.map(C_obj => (
    <C C_obj={C_obj} fn_callback={fn_callback}></C>
  ));
};

const C = (C_obj_init, fn_callback): JSX.Element => {
  const [C_obj, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, C_obj_init);

  useEffect(() => {
    fn_callback(C_obj);
  }, [C_obj, fn_callback]);

  return <div>{C.toString()}</div>;
};
```

Comment: It's so hard to understand. Can you please mark up all components in one code block here?

Comment: Done! I added the block of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing bolt for this thing to work was to handle the rerendering of component C. The problem was that useReducer initial state is applied only once, then not when the component is rendered. Therefore, there is a need to force the update of the `obj_c` when re-rendering it. To do that, I added an extra dispatch action in the Component C body.

```js
useEffect(() => {                                                                                                                                                                           
    dispatch({                                                                                                                                                                                
      kind: Kind.UPDATE,                                                                                                                                                                      
      payload: {                                                                                                                                                                              
        obj_C: C_obj_init,                                                                                                                                                                        
      },                                                                                                                                                                                      
    });                                                                                                                                                                                       
  }, [C_obj_init]);
```

which associated case in the reducer is

```js
  switch (action.kind) {                                                                       
    case Kind.UPDATE:                                                                          
      return action.payload.obj_C;
```

An important thing point here is to not return a recreated obj_C, this wouldlead to an infinite loop to this other hook seen earlier:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    fn_callback(C_obj);
  }, [C_obj, fn_callback]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that you mean

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useReducer, useCallback } from "react"

type SomeObj = {
  name: string
  key: string
}

const A = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [items, setitems] = useState<SomeObj[]>([
    {
      key: "a",
      name: "hello"
    }
  ])

  return (
    <>
      <B items={items} setitems={setitems} />
    </>
  )
}

const B = ({ items, setitems }: { items: SomeObj[]; setitems: (x: SomeObj[]) => void }): JSX.Element => {
  const [items2, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (
      x: SomeObj[],
      a: {
        kind: string
        payload: {}
      }
    ) => {
      return x
    },
    items
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    setitems(items2)
  }, [items2, setitems])

  const fn_callback = useCallback(
    (item: SomeObj) =>
      dispatch({
        kind: "update",
        payload: { wells_plan: item },
      }),
    []
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {items2.map((item) => (
        <C itemInit={item} fn_callback={fn_callback} key={item.key}></C>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const C = ({ itemInit, fn_callback }: { itemInit: SomeObj; fn_callback: (c_obj: SomeObj) => void }): JSX.Element => {
  const [item, dispatch] = useReducer((x: SomeObj) => x, itemInit)

  useEffect(() => {
    fn_callback(item)
  }, [item, fn_callback])

  return <div>{item.name}</div>
}

function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <A></A>
    </main>
  )
}

export default App
```

And, I think, it's basically the reason for using global/atom state managers to react like: `redux`, `recoil`, `jotai`, etc.

In your scenario, you have a couple of prop passing layers through components, and only if I understand correctly, you try to take up changes from deeply nested component.

Using global state, you can have only one array and source of truth, and only one handler in each child component. That probably will remove all unnecessary hooks

Comment: Yes, my snippet is pretty conceptual but that is as you said. TBH I was hoping to do everything with standards hooks, but maybe I should start looking into redux. Hopefully what was learned with the hooks will make the transition to Redux faster. Thanks for your time

Comment: @zakrapovic To simplify the study look also to @redux/toolkit from Redux developers, it would help significantly reduce boilerplate. I recommend use atom state (recoil (from react devs), jotai)

Comment: @zakrapovic, But hooks variant will really look like this. I think, It should be as it is